# Updating Google Fusion Table Row via $.ajax() POST

Tags: jquery, sql, row, google-fusion-tables

I'm attempting to update a row in a Google fusion table using the jQuery $.ajax() method (shown in the php page below). If I change the 'type' in the .$.ajax() method to GET and try a SELECT statement I get the expected data returned, but when I try an UPDATE statement using POST nothing happens. The query statement is based in the following [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide#Updating). Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong would be very appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<?php 
//Include fusion table php libraries
include('Libs/clientlogin.php'); 
include('Libs/sql.php'); 
include('Libs/file.php'); 
$username=<MY USER NAME>; 
$password=<MY PASSWORD>; 
$token=ClientLogin::getAuthToken($username,$password); 
$ftclient=new FTClientLogin($token); 
?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
var token = "<?= $token ?>";

        function updateTable() {
            var URL = "https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query/?sql=UPDATE <TABLEID> SET <COLUMN NAME> ='new value' WHERE ROWID =<SOME ROW ID>";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: URL,
                dataType: "jsonp",

                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    //name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                 beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + token);
                },
                success: function run(data) {},


            });

        }
    </script>
    <a href="" " data-role="button " onclick="updateTable(); return
    false " rel="external ">Post</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could be the comma in `maxRows: 12,` which doesn't need to be there if the next line is a comment :) Otherwise use your browser's developer tools (F12 in Chrome) to see if you're getting any syntax errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried taking out the comma and that didn't seem to make a different. As I mentioned this basic set up was working for a SELECT statement so the 'bones' of the sytax should be sound. I did check out the Chrome developer tool, it looks cool but I still haven't figured out where it shows syntax errors.

Comment: When you use SELECT the `jsonp` parameter is fine, because it allows you to overcome the same-origin-policy. With the POST method this is not possible and unfortunately Google does not yet support POST directly from the browser. You have to sign up for the Trusted Tester API in order to get this to work. But if you use PHP anyway you could just send the request via PHP, which already works.

Answer (score 2):

I would *highly* recommend not printing out the access token in the JavaScript code, where it will be visible to anyone who views the source.

As Odi mentioned, the Trusted Tester API offers a good solution. Here's an example of it in action:

http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/javascript-api.html

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll mark your answer correct as soon as Google lets me into the Trusted Tester API so I can verify it.

Comment: I've been approved for the Trusted Tester API. My app essentially uses the fusion table as a database. So I need to implement a web service auth process instead of a user auth process. I'm having trouble adapting this example to my use case as well as finding a more pertinent example. If you could advise me on this or point me toward any resources it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need a service account: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount. Last I checked, the JavaScript library does not support service accounts yet. In the meantime, you can send the requests in your PHP code instead.